# UI5 seperate press event for Icon in ListItem

Tags: jquery, event-handling, icons, sapui5

I have a *List* with *StandardListItem* with an icon (the one from [THIS example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586513/ui5-dynamically-build-listitems-from-json-with-different-icons)). 
The *StandardListItems* got a press event to handle a function now:

```
<List id="test-list" items="{
    path   : '/products', 
    sorter : [{
        path       : 'prodName', 
        descending : true
    }]
}">
    <items>
        <StandardListItem title="{prodName}" 
                          description="{prodCountry}" 
                          press="onListPress" 
                          type="Active"
                          icon="{
                            path:'price', 
                            formatter:'.getIconFlag'
                            }" 
        />
    </items>    
</List>
```

Now I'd like to have a simple Tooltip displayed (showing e.g. the prodName) when clicking on the Icon (and then positioning the tooltip relative to the icon although it is not a seperate control). Problem: The press event is fired for the whole StandardListItem including the icon. I did not find out if this is possible, but based on the markup I think is has to be, because the icon is a seperate DOM element. 
[image]
´.getIcon()´ just returns the String URI for the icon property, so .. Is it possible to handle a seperate press/click event for the icon "section"?

[EDIT:]
I solved it: What I wanted is the same as in [THIS post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183381/how-to-have-click-event-only-fire-on-parent-div-not-children) 
I can access the target by:
`oEvent.getSource()._event.target` and then look if my target has class `"sapUiIcon"` and either return false or call another function.

[image]

THX for any advice hwo to access the target information ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `CustomListItem` instead and use a separate `sap.ui.core.Icon` with it's own `press` event.

But you probably need to check if the press from the listitem does not interfere with the press from the icon

Answer (score 1):

You should use type ActiveAndDetail then you can attach your "detail" event handler(like press) only for the icon.