# SAPUI5 List Path Parameter : Cannot pass the constructed string

Tags: xml, sapui5

I am trying to enter the below constructed path in the path parameter of List element of a XML view: dataremote>/Categories({dataremote>CategoryID})/Products.

1) I have checked the value of 'dataremote>/Categories({dataremote>CategoryID})/Products' coming as 'dataremote>/Categories(4)/Products' in debug .

but when I use  'dataremote>/Categories({dataremote>CategoryID})/Products' as the path of the List parameter path , No data is fetched .

2) Now if I put hardcoded 'dataremote>/Categories(4)/Products' as the value of the path parameter, then list is getting populated , I have tried all options but not sure why this is happening, they both should work as they have same string value .

```
   <List
      id="CatList"
      class="sapUiResponsiveMargin"
      width="auto"
      items="{
      path : 'dataremote>/Categories({dataremote>CategoryID})/Products'
            ,
      parameters : { select: 'ProductID,ProductName '}
            }">
```

Rishi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UI5: Dynamically build ListItems from JSON with different Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586513/ui5-dynamically-build-listitems-from-json-with-different-icons)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using the binding from controller !

Thanks !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586513/ui5-dynamically-build-listitems-from-json-with-different-icons